# Assertion Error in Python with Google App Engine Users.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am attempting to make use of the google app engine to have a login system for a site I am building using Webapp2 in python. Upon attempting to access the root page however, I receive this error

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/Data2/programming/Media-Management/src/server/main_server.py", line 199, in get
user = users.get_current_user()
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 311, in get_current_user
return User()
  File "/home/allen/.local/share/virtualenvs/Media-Management--7fPVcRX/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 102, in __init__
assert _auth_domain
AssertionError
```

The code section that it errors on is as follows:

```html
class LoginHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        
        user = users.get_current_user()
        myPage = """
          <html>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <h2>Google App Engine Login - Python Web app</h2>
                    <h3>Welcome, {0}. This is a sample page!</h3>
                    <a href="{1}"><b>Click here to {2}</b></a>
                </div>
            </body>
          </html>
          """
      
        if user:
            myData = myPage.format(user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/"),'logout' )
        else:
            myData = myPage.format('Guest', users.create_login_url("/"),'login' )
            
        return myData
```

Comment: The local devserver comes with this in its default environment: `'AUTH_DOMAIN': 'gmail.com'`, are you somehow overwriting it?

Comment: Would it work if you used the version of webapp2 bundled with the SDK, instead of the version installed in your `site-packages` folder?

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Cornilescu commented, setting the following environment variable fixes this

```
os.environ["AUTH_DOMAIN"] = 'gmail.com'
```